# Выбор данных в MS Access по дню, месяцу и году

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Проблема**: необходимо вывести данные о товарах, которые прибыли в заданное пользователем время (пользователю в начале предлагается ввести дату От и До).

Я знаю функцию Year, которая позволяет работать с годом, однако, необходимо, чтобы была возможность ввода полной, точной даты (т.е. дд.мм.гггг).

```
WHERE (Year(Товары.Дата_прихода)>=[Введите дату(год) от:] And Year(Товары.Дата_прихода)<=[Введите дату(год) до:]);
```

Как можно сделать выборку не только по году, но и еще по дню и дате (пользователь вводит день, месяц и год)?

**Upd.** Убираю Year:

```
WHERE (Товары.Дата_прихода)>=[Введите дату от:] And (Товары.Дата_прихода)<=[Введите дату до:];
```

Пробую вводить данные в формате дд.мм.гггг (11.11.2017 и 12.10.2018). Выдает:
[image: Сообщение после ввода данных]

Comment: уберите year, а дату вводите в формате дд.мм.гггг

Comment: дополнил вопрос. проблема еще имеется

Comment: у меня работает. А что у вас в региональных настройках `[Язык и региональные стандарты]-[Форматы]-[Краткая дата]`?

Comment: уже разобрался! спасибо вам! проблема заключалась в том, что вводил даты в формате 11.11.2017 (т.е. через точку), а в системе стоит ввод через черту /. Так что нужно было вводить 11/11/2017. Все работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по комментариям, вы уже разобрались в проблеме, однако хочу обратить внимание, что вы можете неверно указывать формат даты. Дело в том, что даты **должны быть строго в формате USA-date**, а именно `#M/D/YYYY#`. Разделитель должен быть именно `/`, а не точка или пробел. Порядок указания месяца и дня так же важны. Сперва указывается месяц, затем день. При этом числа должны быть в односимвольном формате (вместо `01-31` для дней и `01-12` для месяца должно быть указано `1-31` и `1-12` соответственно). Дата с обоих сторон заключается в решетку `#`.